# Kotlin Infinite Recursion

Tags: kotlin, recursion

```
val minesAround = checkIfMinesAround(column, row)
            if (!minesAround) {
                explore(column, row)

private fun explore(column: Int, row: Int) {
        displayedMinefield[row][column] = Symbol.FCell.symbol
        for (rowNumber in determineRange(row, minefield.lastIndex)) {
            for (columnNumber in determineRange(column, minefield[rowNumber].lastIndex)) {
                if (displayedMinefield[rowNumber][columnNumber] == Symbol.FCell.symbol) continue

                displayedMinefield[rowNumber][columnNumber] = minefield[rowNumber][columnNumber]
                if (!checkIfMinesAround(rowNumber, columnNumber)) {
                    explore(rowNumber, columnNumber)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkIfMinesAround(row: Int, column: Int): Boolean {
        var minesAround = false
        for (rowNumber in determineRange(row, minefield.lastIndex)) {
            for (columnNumber in determineRange(column, minefield[rowNumber].lastIndex)) {
                if (minefield[rowNumber][columnNumber] == Symbol.Mine.symbol) {
                    minesAround = true
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return minesAround
    }

private fun determineRange(num1: Int, num2: Int) =
        when (num1) {
            0 -> 0..1
            num2 -> num1 - 1..num2
            else -> num1 - 1..num1 + 1
        }
```

I'm recreating minesweeper, and the logic above is for exploring cells. I have a 9x9 minefield, and when a user wants to explore a cell that doesn't contain a mine, the above code runs. It first checks the surroundings for mines (3 cells for corners, 5 cells for sides, and 8 cells for anything in the middle), then explores the surroundings if there aren't any mines. In that case, it should also check if any surrounding cells are in the same situation (meaning they also have no mines around them), and if they don't have any mines around them, they should automatically be explored as well. That's why I have the recursive call. However, I run into a stackoverflowerror due to the explore function running forever. Where does the logic go wrong? Below is the minefield.

```
 |123456789|
-|---------|
1|.........|
2|.........|
3|.........|
4|.........|
5|.........|
6|.........|
7|.........|
8|.........|
9|.........|
-|---------|
```

Comment: You might want to look up "breadth first search" - essentially, you keep a queue of cells that need to be searched and terminate when that's empty.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to provide a precise answer in such a complex case, but generally speaking when you explore cells you have to mark them as explored and then ignore them in further exploring. Otherwise, you keep exploring already explored cells over and over again. For example, if you explore `(5,5)` it will invoke exploring of `(6,5)`, which in turn will explore `(5,5)`, then `(6,5)` and so on.

By looking into your code I think this will do the trick:

```kotlin
if (displayedMinefield[i][j] == Symbol.FCell.symbol) continue

displayedMinefield[i][j] = minefield[i][j]
if (!checkIfMinesAround(i, j)) {
    explore(i, j)
}
```

Although, I may be wrong. I'm not sure what `FCell` is.

Also, you order columns and rows inconsistently across your code. For example, functions receive parameters `row` and then `column` and arrays use `column` first, then `row`. While this is not a bug itself, it makes much easier to introduce bugs. Actually, I think you introduced bugs because of that. In `explore()` you pass `i` which is column as row to both `explore()` and `checkIfMinesAround()`. Same for `j`. It would be easier to spot the problem if you use meaningful names and not just `i` and `j`.

Comment: I just edited my post with my updated code. I'm still getting the same error, though. Why is the logic still wrong? Note: FCell is a cell that has been explored.

Comment: `explore()` still receives params in the wrong order (actually, you just changed it to this order ;-P ). Please fix before we'll move on, because maybe it is a reason.